# Windows phone universal app is using camera only one time

Tags: camera, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

In my app I have a button which open camera, take picture and do some processing on it and return back to previous page with the results.

Now Problem is this that it works one time and on second time it open other page but doesn't show camera. Then I have to completely close my application and again launch it to make it work.

I think this is happening because when I am taking picture first time, I open camera, capture it in a captureElement and when I open it second time the previous code is using camera or some thing. I thing there is some thing to close camera which i am missing.

Comment: Please add the relevant code - without it it's hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: This might be happening due to some problem with camera initialization code. As Romasz mentioned a code sample would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize camera every time you navigate to the page that contains it (`OnNavigatedTo` method). If you want to write a good code you have to deactive camera every time you leave the page (`OnNavigatedFrom` method). I hope this could be help you.